# Does "fair complexion" mean light or white skin color?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I am having trouble understanding definitive meaning of describing one's skin tone as "fair complexion". Is it meant to be used strictly in reference to white skin? Can it be used in other contexts?

Comment: What other context are you thinking of? See https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fair-skinned

Comment: Among white-skinned English speakers, it refers to how easy it is to get sunburned. Fair-skinned white people burn easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word ***fair*** dates back to before 900 A.D. and is of Anglo-Saxon origin.

It came into use when the vast majority of English speakers were Caucasian and (this is the main point) lighter skin hues, especially in women, were favored over darker ones, possibly because it was considered good form for noble women to avoid direct exposure to the sun, something that many common women could not avoid as they worked outdoors.

*Swarthy* was, and still is, the opposite of *fair*.

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/fair

Comment: You had me until you brought in "swarthy."  But I think you could take that sentence out, as I don't think the OP was asking about an antonym.

Answer (score 0):

The OED has an entry for **local white**

> n. *Caribbean (originally)* a white colonist or settler in the Caribbean; (later) a descendent of these people; *a Caribbean person of European or mixed ancestry, **having a light or fair complexion.***

**To have a fair complexion** is thus a relative term -> to have a complexion that is fairer than might be expected.

Comment: Your logic is not convincing for me.  The definition of "local white" you gave doesn't seem to be saying that "light-skinned black" would be one of the meanings of "fair."  Let's face it, it's an old-fashioned word, which doesn't work well outside the old-fashioned assumption of a Venn diagram in which the whole rectangle, or universe, is made up of white people (Caucasians).

Comment: @aparente001 -*The definition of "local white" you gave doesn't seem to be saying that "light-skinned black" would be one of the meanings of "fair."* What other genetic effect do you think is intended by  "local **whites**" who are identified by having European ancestry?

Comment: I didn't think the goal was to define "local whites," but to define "fair complexion."

Comment: @aparente001 as the two are inseparable, it is hard to see your objection. From personal experience in a "Black" country, I can tell you that locals often describe each other by the shade of their skin, much as Europeans do.

Comment: @aparente001 *Let's face it, it's an old-fashioned word,* Hello! Nobody is suggesting "local-white"... The quote is an example of use of "**fair complexion**", which is what the questioner asks...

Comment: Re your comment #1 -- racism is racism, and you are not *required* to promote and perpetuate it. / Why put *Black* in quotes?  Were you saying "experience in a so-called Black country"? Re your comment #2, there is no shortage of example sentences containing the phrase "fair complexion."  Why use a definition of an obscure term to document your answer?

Comment: I appreciate that you are "woke" to a remarkable degree and that your virtue has been signalled. *"Why use a definition of an obscure term to document your answer?"* I had hoped that the reader would take the quote to show that Blacks use the term too and thus "fair complexion" is not only applicable to Europeans. If you do not understand why I used "Black" country, I suggest you ask a new question about it in ELL.

Comment: I just wondered why the quotes.  Anyway, currently, in the US, at least, an African American or Black person with a lighter skin color would typically be called *light-skinned black, light-skinned, mixed race*, or *mixed*, and these descriptors may be heard from speakers of any race.